# Can I put button inside the a tag in pug?

Tags: button, pug

I wonder can I put button inside the a tag in pug! Code is like below.

```
a(href=routes.menu)
    button
```

I would appreciate your reply. thank you

Comment: Not best practice. But sure, you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

HTML *forbids* buttons from appearing inside anchors.

- If you want a link, use an `<a>`.
- If you want to submit a form, use a `<button>`.
- If you want something to trigger JavaScript from and cannot write [Unobtrusive JS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), then use a `<button type="button">`.

Then apply CSS to make it look the way you want.